Why does an Ellipse's Fill's ImageSource property, not accepting an ImageSource object type?
I have a DependencyProperty of type ImageSource named "Image".
public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Image), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(CellView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
public ImageSource Image
{
    get 
    {
        return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageProperty);
    }
    set 
    { 
        SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
    }
}

And I bind two elements to this DependencyProperty using TemplateBinding
 <Image x:Name="_1" Source="{TemplateBinding Image}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="30" Width="30"/>

 <Ellipse x:Name="_2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Uniform">
     <Ellipse.Fill>
         <ImageBrush  ImageSource="{TemplateBinding Image}" Stretch="Fill"></ImageBrush>
     </Ellipse.Fill>
 </Ellipse>

The assignment works for <Image> element's Source property (Successfully seeing the image in the UI), while the assignment doesn't work for <Ellipse.Fill.ImageBrush>'s ImageSource property. (Returning NULL as I checked using the debugger output)
Here's how I implemented a simple debugging method:
 public override void OnApplyTemplate()
 {            
     image = Template.FindName("_1", this) as Image;
     ellipse = Template.FindName("_2", this) as Ellipse;
     button = Template.FindName("_3", this) as Button;

     button.Click += Button_Click;

     base.OnApplyTemplate();
 }

 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     var y = image.Source.ToString();
     var x = ((ImageBrush)ellipse.Fill).ToString();
     var z = ((ImageBrush)ellipse.Fill).ImageSource;

     Debug.WriteLine(y);
     Debug.WriteLine(x);
     Debug.WriteLine(z == null);
 }

Debugger Output (On Button Click)
pack://application:,,,/MVVM-TrafficLight;component/Resources/Images/Yellow.png
System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush
True
I can fix this by implementing a separate DependencyProperty for the Ellipse.Fill.ImageBrush's ImageSource property. However, what I do want to know is why the assignment does not work, because as far as I know you need to supply an ImageSource object to an ImageSource property, which is exactly what I am doing. Is there anything that I am missing here?
Note: TemplateBinding works.

Because the object that defines the binding is nested into a property (property element syntax) TemplateBinding can't resolve the source at compiletime.
Instead, replace {TemplateBinding} with {RelativeSource TemplatedParent}:
<Ellipse>
  <Ellipse.Fill>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Image}" />
  </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>

Sometimes we have to wait until the template is completely applied in order to resolve a property path. In this case the binding has to be evaluated at runtime (RelativeSource markup extension) and not compiletime (TemplateBinding markup extension).

It turns out that you need to pass an imageUri (string) to this property.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imagebrush.imagesource?view=windowsdesktop-8.0
<object ImageSource="imageUri"/>

The property names can be confusing sometimes!
